# Lost Android debugger but app keeps running normal

Tags: android, opengl-es

I'm developing for android (API 14) deploying for Nexus One on Genymotion simulator and to a Galaxy Note N8000 tablet, but my app it's having a strange behaviour: in one of the activities, when I press the back button, the app shows the right activity but my debugger disconnects.

Using the simulated Nexus One I have a log message related to OpenGL out of memory and I've found out that OpenGL support for simulators it's usually bad, but using physical note n8000 I have nothing in my logs that can help me. The app behaves like it should but I loose debugging.

Does anyone had a problem similar to that? How did you fix it?

Answer (score 1):

I face the same issue sometimes, my guess is that the `Exception` actually forces application closing (disconnecting it from debugger), but somehow it gets automatically restarted restoring the previous 'state'.

In your case, maybe is just a simulator issue, but you should consider testing in a real *Nexus One* device, just to make sure.